# Ubuntu boots to a grub prompt

Tags: 12.10, wubi

So I installed Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit, as was recommended. I used the windows installer (*Wubi*). I rebooted my computer and when the choices of which OS I would like to start I choose **Ubuntu**. After i press enter it just goes to what i am thinking is a command prompt screen.

It has the word `grub>`. I do not know what to do next.
I tried a few command prompts but nothing

I am using an IBM think Pad with a Pentium M 1600MHz processor  512 RAM
did I do something wrong? do i need the 64 bit? or do i need the 12.04 download? how do i uninstall it if i need to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: What is the output of `search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk` and `echo $root`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. what i had to do was to uninstall everything i had on my laptop and install ubuntu. That was foolish of me. And fortunately, my Ubuntu still did not boot, and showed a grub prompt. 
later i realised that this was a UEFI mode problem. What you need to do is

**First**, disable uefi boot mode. and then try installing ubuntu. (NOTE: the problem isnt with your ubuntu 12.10 image). you also need to disable your secure boot. install in legacy boot mode.

OR

**Second**, live run your ubuntu OS, use boot repair. this must be added using apt-get repository. OR use **LINUX SECURE REMIX** which is essentially made to solve this problem of dual booting. it comes with a preinstalled package called boot repair, run it to modify your booting options in favour of your linux distribution. simply live run your Operating system ie Ubuntu and run boot repair available in the dock on the left. 
then install the OS.

this worked for me. here is the reference for more technical info and the link to the linux secure remix image.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxSecureRemix

Comment: Note, the OP said he installed Ubuntu using WUBI in a Pentium M box which was probably built long before UEFI came into our world.

Comment: my bad.. in that case,i think u need to reinstall grub. for me, the remedy was UEFI disabling. reinstall grub using ubuntu live run. refer this for more details. [link](http://superuser.com/questions/185484/straight-to-grub-prompt-on-boot) @user68186